# How to check Data Grid column value in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

How to check Data Grid column value  in WPF

i want to check textbox value exist in data grid column 1 in wpf.

how can i do that?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
private void yourGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
      if (yourGrid.SelectedItem == null) return;
        DataRowView dr = yourGrid.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
        DataRow dr1 = dr.Row;

        string value1 = dr1.ItemArray[0];
        string value2 = dr1.ItemArray[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were using WPF correctly, then you'd already have access to all of the values from the `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourItemCollection}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In this example, an `ObservableCollection<YourDataType>` collection named `YourItemCollection` contains all of the data. The `DataGrid` will automatically add a row for each item in this collection. The collection is of type `YourDataType`. This data type class defines a `FirstName` property and that is data bound to this column.

To access the data in the column of the `DataGrid`, all we need to do is to look at the `FirstName` property of the selected item in the data bound collection. We can make this even easier by binding a `YourDataType SelectedItem` property to the `DataGrid.SelectedItem` property... now we can just look at the `FirstName` property of the object specified by the `SelectedItem` property.

You can find out more from the [`DataGrid` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.